# http concurrent delays with goroutines in background

Tags: go, concurrency

Why is there such a delay in processing of incoming requests by the main server goroutine and how can this delay be avoided ?

Simple code with **NO DELAYS**

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", root)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  http handlers
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("[root] `%v`\n", r.URL.Path)
    w.Write([]byte("What the hell"))
}
```

Result testing the loading

```
    ╰─➤  wrk -d20s -t5 -c100 http://localhost:8090
Running 20s test @ http://localhost:8090
  5 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency    17.07ms   46.63ms 368.77ms   91.73%
    Req/Sec    10.99k     4.87k   24.48k    62.49%
  1038912 requests in 20.10s, 128.80MB read
Requests/sec:  51684.63
Transfer/sec:      6.41MB
```

Adding goroutines

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
func main() {
    _ = NewTesterGo(100)

    http.HandleFunc("/", root)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8090", nil)
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  http handlers
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
func root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Printf("[root] `%v`\n", r.URL.Path)
    w.Write([]byte("What the fuck"))
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  tester segment
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
type (
    TesterGo struct {
        Work chan string
    }
)

func NewTesterGo(count int) *TesterGo {
    t:=&TesterGo{
        Work:make(chan string,100),
    }
    for ; count > 0 ; count -- {
        go t.Worker()
    }
    return t

}
func (t *TesterGo) Worker() {
    log.Printf("[testergo][worker][work] стартовал....\n")
    for {
        select {
        case work := <-t.Work:
            log.Printf("[testerGo][Worker] %v\n", work)
        default:
        }
    }
}
```

Result  with loading

```
╰─➤  wrk -d20s -t5 -c100 http://localhost:8090
Running 20s test @ http://localhost:8090
  5 threads and 100 connections
  Thread Stats   Avg      Stdev     Max   +/- Stdev
    Latency   464.71ms  305.44ms   1.90s    77.90%
    Req/Sec    54.62     43.74   200.00     67.50%
  3672 requests in 20.05s, 466.17KB read
  Socket errors: connect 0, read 0, write 0, **timeout 97**
Requests/sec:    **183.11**
Transfer/sec:     23.25KB
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your goroutines use `default`, causing them to spin immediately if there is nothing in the channel (and there is nothing in your example). This probably makes Go's scheduler do way more context switching than needed, and probably consume a lot of CPU for nothing.

Is there a reason to `default` in a loop? If not try one of the following:

Either no default, the goroutines would simply "sleep" until there's work.

```
 for {
        select {
        case work := <-t.Work:
            log.Printf("[testerGo][Worker] %v\n", work)
        }
    }
```

This BTW makes the select completely redundant, so just get rid of it:

```
 for { //you can also use a range on the channel
     work := <- t.Work 
     log.Printf("[testerGo][Worker] %v\n", work)
 }
```

Second option - a timeout that will make them wait before continuing in the loop:

```
 for {
        select {
        case work := <-t.Work:
            log.Printf("[testerGo][Worker] %v\n", work)

        case <- time.After(100*time.Millisecond): //or whatever you prefer

        }
    }
```

Comment: Exactly. Thank you for pointing out the reasons. Who is around to benchmarking, performance returned to normal. Thank you.

Comment: If no `default` in `select` just one `case`, then there isn't a need for `select`. Worth pointing out.